# How to create a flag column indicating change based on the change in value from the previous value to current value per ID in a pandas dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, pandas-groupby

I have a data frame that is sorted by `CLIENT_ID` and `ENCOUNTER_DATE` as shown below:

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | STAGE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | 1 |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | 1 |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | 2 |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | 1 |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | 1 |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | 2 |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | 2 |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | 3 |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | 4 |
| 8400 | 2020-12-31 | 1 |
| 8401 | 2017-08-29 | 1 |
| 8401 | 2017-09-15 | 3 |
| 8500 | 2018-10-10 | 2 |

How can I create a new column (flag column) which indicates whether or not the `STAGE` from the previous `DATE_ENCOUNTER` for each `CLIENT_ID` is greater than the current `DATE_ENCOUNTER` which would result in the table below:

| CLIENT_ID | ENCOUNTER_DATE | STAGE | STAGE_WORSENED |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 8222 | 2020-01-01 | 1 | 0 |
| 8222 | 2020-03-02 | 1 | 0 |
| 8222 | 2020-04-18 | 2 | 1 |
| 8222 | 2020-07-31 | 1 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2017-06-10 | 1 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2017-09-11 | 2 | 1 |
| 8300 | 2018-02-01 | 2 | 0 |
| 8300 | 2018-04-01 | 3 | 1 |
| 8300 | 2018-05-31 | 4 | 1 |
| 8400 | 2020-12-31 | 1 | 0 |
| 8401 | 2017-08-29 | 1 | 0 |
| 8401 | 2017-09-15 | 3 | 1 |
| 8500 | 2018-10-10 | 2 | 0 |

Here is the code to generate the df:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"CLIENT_ID": [8222, 8222, 8222, 8222, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8300, 8400, 8401, 8401, 8500],
                   "ENCOUNTER_DATE": ['2020-01-01', '2020-03-02', '2020-04-18', '2020-07-31', '2017-06-10', '2017-09-11', '2018-02-01', '2018-04-01', '2018-05-31', '2020-12-31', '2017-08-29', '2017-09-15', '2018-10-10'],
                   "STAGE": [1, 1, 2, 1, 1, 2, 2, 3, 4, 1, 1, 3, 2]})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`DataFrameGroupBy.diff`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.core.groupby.DataFrameGroupBy.diff.html) with compare for greater or equal by `1` and cast to integers:

```
df['STAGE_WORSENED'] = df.groupby('CLIENT_ID')['STAGE'].diff().ge(1).astype(int)
print (df)
    CLIENT_ID ENCOUNTER_DATE  STAGE  STAGE_WORSENED
0        8222     2020-01-01      1               0
1        8222     2020-03-02      1               0
2        8222     2020-04-18      2               1
3        8222     2020-07-31      1               0
4        8300     2017-06-10      1               0
5        8300     2017-09-11      2               1
6        8300     2018-02-01      2               0
7        8300     2018-04-01      3               1
8        8300     2018-05-31      4               1
9        8400     2020-12-31      1               0
10       8401     2017-08-29      1               0
11       8401     2017-09-15      3               1
12       8500     2018-10-10      2               0
```

Comment: would you use ne(0) if you wanted to create a STAGE_DIFFERENT field i.e, the previous stage is different from the current stage?

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 - How looks expected ouput?

Comment: If you look at the previous print statement, the only different would be for index = 4, STAGE_WORSENED = 1

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 - Do you think `8300     2017-06-10      1` ? Or `8222     2020-07-31      1` ?

Comment: No because it's the first entries for that specific CLIENT_ID

Comment: @Mazil_tov998 - Can you check `s = df.groupby('CLIENT_ID')['STAGE'].diff()
df['STAGE_WORSENED'] = (s.ge(1) | (s.isna() & df['CLIENT_ID'].eq(8300))).astype(int)` ?

Comment: @jez_rael `df = df.sort_values(by=['CLIENT_ID', 'ENCOUNTER_DATE'])
    df['LAST_STAGE'] = df.groupby(['CLIENT_ID'])['STAGE'].shift(1).fillna(-1).astype('int8')
    df['DIFFERENT_LAST_STAGE'] = -1
    df.loc[df['STAGE']==df['LAST_STAGE'],'DIFFERENT_LAST_STAGE'] = 0
    df.loc[(df['STAGE']!=df['LAST_STAGE'])&(df['LAST_STAGE']!=-1),'DIFFERENT_LAST_STAGE'] = 1
    df['DIFFERENT_LAST_STAGE'] = df['DIFFERENT_LAST_STAGE'].astype('int8')` this worked. Thanks

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/237164/discussion-between-mazil-tov998-and-jezrael).